# ¿Cómo comparar cadenas con tilde (acento gráfico)?

Tags: java

Tengo que comparar la igualdad de unas cadenas pero debo ignorar las tildes (o acento gráfico); he buscado en la documentación y descubrí que puedo usar [`StringUtils.stripAcents`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents(java.lang.String)) de Apache Commons.

```
"arbol".equals(StringUtils.stripAcents("árbol")) // verdadero
```

Pero el problema es que este método está disponible desde la versión 3.0 y no puedo actualizar mi proyecto, que usa 2.x.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo de otro modo?

Comment: Ya que es open source puedes tomar código de la versión que si tiene el método e incluirlo en tu proyecto

Answer (score 5):

Para realizar correctamente la comparación, hace falta un algoritmo de ordenación alfabética multinivel. En Java puedes usar `java.text.Collator`, o mejor aún, el *Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA)* disponible en ICU.

Para ambos algoritmos, una comparación a nivel primario ignora diferencias en diacríticos o mayúsculas, una comparación a nivel secundario ignora diferencias en mayúsculas, ...

Normalmente, se utilizaría una comparación a nivel primario (ignorando diacríticos, mayúsculas, ...), para buscar una cadena, mientras que una comparación a nivel terciario o incluso cuaternario es muy útil para generar listas ordenadas.

```
// Comentando/descomentando los dos siguientes imports, se puede elegir
//  entre el Collator de Java, o la implementación UCA de ICU

//import java.text.Collator;
import com.ibm.icu.text.Collator;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Tildes {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Collator c = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es"));
                c.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
                System.out.println("arbol " + (c.equals("arbol","árbol")?"eq":"ne") + " árbol");
                System.out.println("RAMA " + (c.equals("RAMA","rama")?"eq":"ne") + " rama");
        }
}
```

A veces, puede interesar ignorar algunos símbolos:

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.Collator;
import com.ibm.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Tildes {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Collator c = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("es"));

                // Comparación con UCA ignorando símbolos de puntuación
                ((RuleBasedCollator) c).setAlternateHandlingShifted(true);
                c.setMaxVariable(Collator.ReorderCodes.PUNCTUATION);
                System.out.println("pinopuente " + 
                    (c.equals("pinopuente","pino-puente")?"eq":"ne") + 
                    " pino-puente");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You uso [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) y una `REGEX`:

ejemplo:

```
    String mystring = "árbol";
    mystring = Normalizer.normalize(mystring , Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    mystring = mystring.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

El valor al evaluar la siguiente expresión:

```
  "arbol".equals(mystring); //verdadero
```

será verdadero.

Answer (score -1):

Para esto es necesario tener un abecedario propio, ya que el que viene por defecto no considera las tildes, o están en un orden desconocido. He diseñado una función llamada `comparaTildes`, que consiste en comparar si un caracter viene después en el abecedario en español.

También desarrollé otra función llamada `comparaCadenas`, que intenta comparar la cadena mediante iteraciones.

Código Java (no probé si funciona):

```
public static int comparaTildes(char a,char b)
{
    String abecedario = "AaÁáBbCcDdEeÉéFfGgHhIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnÑñOoÓóPpQqRrSsTtUuÚúVvWwXxYyZz";

    int posicionA=abecedario.indexOf(a);
    int posicionB=abecedario.indexOf(b);

    if(posicionA<posicionB){return -1;}
    if(posicionA>posicionB){return 1;}

    return 0;
}
public static int comparaCadenas(String cadena_a, String cadena_b)
{
    for (int i=0; i<cadena_a.length() & i<cadena_b.length(); i++)
    {
        char a = cadena_a.charAt(i);
        char b = cadena_b.charAt(i);
        int esMayor = comparaTildes(a,b);
        if(esMayor == -1){return -1;}
        if(esMayor == 1){return 1;}
    }
    if(i == cadena_a.length()){return -1;}
    if(i == cadena_b.length()){return 1;}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Para esto es necesario tener un abecedario propio*: Tal como lo demuestra la respuesta mas arriba, no hay necesidad de reinventar la rueda. Es mejor usar código bien establecido y maduro que una solución propia.

Comment: @sstan Ya veo, entonces usan `java.text.Collator` y `java.text.Normalizer`. La verdad es que mi manera es como me la enseñó el profesor de algoritmos, no sabía que habían otras formas.

Comment: Este algoritmo no funciona: _visión <<  visionario_ Para realizar correctamente la comparación, es necesario un algoritmo multinivel, que funciona como si se comparara por niveles, es decir, primero se comparan letras bases sin diacríticos, después, los empates se resuelven teniendo en cuenta diacríticos, después, se desempata teniendo en cuenta mayúsculas contra minúsculas, ...

Comment: @ninjalj Buena idea... Sería un poco más complejo el código, pero es más correcto. Sería necesario homogeneizar los caracteres de las palabras antes de comparar, teniendo una copia.